# I have downloaded pyaudio.whl but instead of running through powershell or cmd , I have used open with other apps

Tags: python-imaging-library, pyaudio, python-wheel

I have downloaded pyaudio.whl but instead of running through powershell or cmd , I have used open with other apps. I tried alot to reverse it in original format but unable to so. now whatever .whl file am downloading its always downloading with other format. Please help to get it reverse in original format so I can run it through cmd.

Comment: They've got instructions on [how to install pyaudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#downloads) on their webpage.  Which OS are you on?